# What does the empty curly braces do in C#`?

Tags: c#

From "Rx.NET in Action" code examples:

```
public class StockTicker : IStockTicker
{
    public event EventHandler<StockTick> StockTick= delegate {}; // <-- (*)

    public void Notify(StockTick tick)
    {
        StockTick(this, tick);
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of the empty curly braces at the position indicated by `(*)`?

Is it just an empty, anonymous object?

Comment: It is an anonymous method. The body has no statements.

Comment: As an aside, the usual approach would be to leave the field at its default (`null`) and use `StockTick?.Invoke(this, tick)` instead. Pre-emptively adding an empty delegate to the event handler feels uncomfortable -- that's a lot of dummy objects if you applied it consistently.

Comment: And if you do so, you'll need to declare it as `event EventHandler<StockTick>?` (assuming you're using nullable checking)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Before C# 6.0's null check operator, this used to be a common way to guarantee that the event delegate list was not null, to prevent race conditions when invoking the delegate.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: this is honestly the first time I've seen it; in ye olden days the "proper" pattern was `EventHandler<StockTick> stockTick = StockTick; if (stockTick != null) stockTick(this, tick);`. This pattern is indeed harder to get right than just sticking in a dummy delegate, so there's something to say for it despite the performance impact. Of course, these days it's unnecessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your pattern has the exact race condition this solved. The proper way was to cache the delegate reference first, before the check so that it couldn't get swapped out from under you. It was far simpler to just assign a null delegate.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: ...caching the delegate is exactly what my code snippet is doing, and is the same thing that `EventHandler?.Invoke()` compiles down to. It seems like you're just restating what I said?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Apologies, you're absolutely right. Reading too fast for my own good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very detailed example as of why this was the case (even if this code does nothing) can be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/c-events-null-checking-initializing-do-nothing-delegate-alexey-khazov/), as well as the differences with the null assignment.

Effectively, as was written in the comments, it was to avoid `.Invoke` null pointer exceptions.

Fact is though that you could still forget it and it gave a false sense of safety.

To answer your question. The `delegate {}` is just an empty function that does nothing.